# create a boxplot in R that labels a box with the sample size (N)

Tags: r, graph, plot, label, boxplot

Is there a way to create a boxplot in R that will display with the box (somewhere) an "N=(sample size)"?  The varwidth logical adjusts the width of the box on the basis of sample size, but that doesn't allow comparisons between different plots.

FWIW, I am using the boxplot command in the following fashion, where 'f1' is a factor:

```
boxplot(xvar ~ f1, data=frame, xlab="input values", horizontal=TRUE)
```

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Here's some ggplot2 code. It's going to display the sample size at the sample mean, making the label multifunctional!

First, a simple function for `fun.data`

```
give.n <- function(x){
   return(c(y = mean(x), label = length(x)))
}
```

Now, to demonstrate with the diamonds data

```
ggplot(diamonds, aes(cut, price)) + 
   geom_boxplot() + 
   stat_summary(fun.data = give.n, geom = "text")
```

You may have to play with the text size to make it look good, but now you have a label for the sample size which also gives a sense of the skew.

Comment: Works great, and looks beautiful.  Thanks!

Comment: What if I'm ggplot-ing with `geom_boxplot(aes(fill=factor(f2)))` where f2 is a second factor - is there a variation on stat_summary that allows for the 'sub boxes' to receive their own N?

Comment: Example code to save space: `ggplot(mpg, aes(manufacturer, hwy, fill = factor(year))) + geom_boxplot() + stat_summary(fun.data = give.n, geom = "text", position = position_dodge(height = 0, width = 0.75), size = 3)` You may have to manually adjust the value passed to `width` in `position_dodge()`

Comment: Position says "unused argument". I am wondering whether one can change the position of the N-count, since it's not readily within the boxplots. thx

Comment: The line in the boxplot is the `median`, so it makes more sense to use `y=median(x)`  -- see the answer at http://stackoverflow.com/a/15720769/1168342

Answer (score 11):

You can use the `names` parameter to write the `n` next to each factor name.

If you don't want to calculate the `n` yourself you could use this little trick:

```
# Do the boxplot but do not show it
b <- boxplot(xvar ~ f1, data=frame, plot=0)
# Now b$n holds the counts for each factor, we're going to write them in names
boxplot(xvar ~ f1, data=frame, xlab="input values", names=paste(b$names, "(n=", b$n, ")"))
```

Comment: How can I put the n number above the box plot horizontal bar for each bar?

Comment: @Dinesh: use the `text` function. You can find the value of the median by looking at the `stats` parameter. For instance: `text(seq_along(f1), b$stats[3,], b$n)`

Answer (score 5):

To get the `n` on top of the bar, you could use `text` with the `stat` details provided by boxplot as follows

```
b <- boxplot(xvar ~ f1, data=frame, plot=0)
text(1:length(b$n), b$stats[5,]+1, paste("n=", b$n))
```

The stats field of b is 
a matrix, each column contains the extreme of the lower whisker, the lower hinge, the median, the upper hinge and the extreme of the upper whisker for one group/plot.

Answer (score 1):

The [`gplots`](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/gplots/index.html) package provides `boxplot.n`, which according to the documentation *produces a boxplot annotated with the number of observations*.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a workaround using the Envstats package. This package needs to be downloaded, loaded and activated using:

```
library(Envstats)
```

The stripChart (different from stripchart) does add to the chart some values such as the n values. First I plotted my boxplot. Then I used the add=T in the stripChart. Obviously, many things were hidden in the stripChart code so that they do not show up on the boxplot. Here is the code I used for the stripChart to hide most items.

[Boxplot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eQuAZ.png) with integrated stripChart to show n values:

```
stripChart(data.frame(T0_G1,T24h_G1,T96h_G1,T7d_G1,T11d_G1,T15d_G1,T30d_G1), show.ci=F,axes=F,points.cex=0,n.text.line=1.6,n.text.cex=0.7,add=T,location.scale.text="none")
```

So boxplot

```
boxplot(data.frame(T0_G1,T24h_G1,T96h_G1,T7d_G1,T11d_G1,T15d_G1,T30d_G1),main="All Rheometry Tests on Egg Plasma at All Time Points at 0.1Hz,0.1% and 37 Set 1,2,3", names=c("0h","24h","96h","7d ", "11d", "15d", "30d"),boxwex=0.6,par(mar=c(8,4,4,2)))
```

Then stripChart

```
stripChart(data.frame(T0_G1,T24h_G1,T96h_G1,T7d_G1,T11d_G1,T15d_G1,T30d_G1), show.ci=F,axes=F,points.cex=0,n.text.line=1.6,n.text.cex=0.7,add=T,location.scale.text="none")
```

You can always adjust the high of the numbers (n values) so that they fit where you want.