# How to add a number of observations per group and use group mean in ggplot2 boxplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, boxplot

I am doing a basic boxplot  where `y=age` and `x=Patient groups`

```
age <- ggplot(data, aes(factor(group2), age))  + ylim(15, 80) 
age + geom_boxplot(fill = "grey80", colour = "#3366FF")
```

I was hoping you could help me out with a few things:

1) Is it possible to include a number of observations per group above each group boxplot (but NOT on the X axis where my group labels are) without having to do this in paint :)? 
 I have tried using:

```
age + annotate("text", x = "CON", y = 60, label = "25")
```

where `CON` is the 1st group and `y = 60` is ~ just above the boxplot for this group. However, the command didn't work. I assume it has something to do that it reads `x` as a continuous rather than a categorical variable.

2) Also although there are plenty of questions about using the mean rather than the median for the boxplots, I still haven`t found a code that works for me?

3) On the same matter is there a way you could include the mean group stat in the boxplot? Perhaps using

```
age + stat_summary(fun.y=mean, colour="red", geom="point")
```

which however only includes a dot of where the mean lies. Or again using

```
age + annotate("text", x = "CON", y = 30, label = "30")
```

where `CON` is the 1st group and `y = 30` is ~ the group age mean. 
Knowing how flexible and rich `ggplot2` syntax is I was hoping that there is a more elegant way of using the real stats output rather than `annotate`.

Any suggestions/links would be much appreciated!

Thanks!!

Comment: A boxplot normally has min, lower, middle and upper quantiles and finally a max value. You already have the .25, .5 and .75 quantiles. Isn't this informative enough?

Comment: This is the format I am asked for.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Is this anything like what you're after? With `stat_summary`, as requested:

```
# function for number of observations 
give.n <- function(x){
  return(c(y = median(x)*1.05, label = length(x))) 
  # experiment with the multiplier to find the perfect position
}

# function for mean labels
mean.n <- function(x){
  return(c(y = median(x)*0.97, label = round(mean(x),2))) 
  # experiment with the multiplier to find the perfect position
}

# plot
ggplot(mtcars, aes(factor(cyl), mpg, label=rownames(mtcars))) +
  geom_boxplot(fill = "grey80", colour = "#3366FF") +
  stat_summary(fun.data = give.n, geom = "text", fun.y = median) +
  stat_summary(fun.data = mean.n, geom = "text", fun.y = mean, colour = "red")
```

Black number is number of observations, red number is mean value. joran's answer shows you how to put the numbers at the top of the boxes
[image]

hat-tip: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3483657/1036500

Comment: For a variation on this answer that includes how to annotate with `n = 11`, etc., see here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15720769/1036500

Answer (score 18):

I think this is what you're looking for maybe?

```
myboxplot <- ddply(mtcars,
                    .(cyl),
                    summarise,
                    min = min(mpg),
                    q1 = quantile(mpg,0.25),
                    med = median(mpg),
                    q3 = quantile(mpg,0.75),
                    max= max(mpg),
                    lab = length(cyl))
ggplot(myboxplot, aes(x = factor(cyl))) + 
    geom_boxplot(aes(lower = q1, upper = q3, middle = med, ymin = min, ymax = max), stat = "identity") + 
    geom_text(aes(y = max,label = lab),vjust = 0)
```

[image]

I just realized I mistakenly used the median when you were asking about the mean, but you can obviously use whatever function for the `middle` aesthetic you please.

Comment: Sorry, one final question. Would it be possible to change the order of the groups? Unfortunately I am not interested in a numeric or data driven order. The only way of doing it I can think of is recoding the group variable. Your help will be much appreciated! thanks again!

Answer (score 4):

Answer to the first problem.
To show value above the box you should provide `x` values as numeric not as level names. So, to plot the value above first value give `x=1`.

```
data(ToothGrowth)
ggplot(ToothGrowth,aes(supp,len))+geom_boxplot()+
   annotate("text",x=1,y=32,label=30)
```

Comment: Hi! Great, thanks. I actually tried both numeric/level initially but for some reason nothing worked. Now it`s fine, thanks a lot.

Comment: The annotate command is perfect to fix positioning issues! Thanks so much