# Error in making a boxplot with ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, boxplot

I tried to make a boxplot today using ggplot2, and I encountered an error I haven't been able to solve, yet.  I have used a similar approach (which I actually took from an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15660829/how-to-add-a-number-of-observations-per-group-and-use-group-mean-in-ggplot2-boxp/15661409#15661409) by user @joran) before without incident, but I must be doing something incorrectly this time.

Here is my data:

`myboxplot<-structure(list(gap = structure(1:2, .Label = c("Jib", "NoJib"), class = "factor"), 
    Location = structure(c(4L, 4L), .Label = c("A", "B", "C", 
    "D"), class = "factor"), min = c(21.809, 21.081), q1 = c(25.582, 
    25.375), med = c(28.082, 27), q3 = c(30.142, 28.622), max = c(37.166, 
    39.808), lab = c(2342L, 119681L)), .Names = c("JibStat", "Location", 
"min", "q1", "med", "q3", "max", "lab"), row.names = c(2L, 7L
), class = "data.frame")`

The code that I have been attempting to use is as follows:

```
ggplot(myboxplot + aes(x=JibStat, fill=JibStat)) +
      geom_boxplot(aes(lower = q1, upper = q3, middle = med, ymin = min, ymax = max), stat = "identity")
```

and I get the following error message:

```
Error in Ops.data.frame(myboxplot, aes(x = JibStat, fill = JibStat)) : list of length 2 not meaningful
```

I have worked on resolving the issue, but I have not been able to find much on resolving the error.  My Google skills must be lacking today, but I can't think of what to search for to get help on this problem.  What is it I am doing wrong here?

Additional info: R version 3.0.1, 64-bit Windows 8.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing the first line to:

```
ggplot(myboxplot, aes(x=JibStat)) +  
    geom_boxplot(aes(lower = q1, upper = q3, middle = med, 
               ymin = min, ymax = max), stat = "identity")
```

I think you'd mis-typed a comma.

Comment: Ah, how embarrassing.  I worked on resolving the error for longer than I care to admit.