# Boxplot show the value of mean

Tags: r, ggplot2

In this boxplot we can see the mean but how can we have also the number value on the plot for every mean of every box plot?

```
 ggplot(data=PlantGrowth, aes(x=group, y=weight, fill=group)) + geom_boxplot() +
     stat_summary(fun.y=mean, colour="darkred", geom="point", 
                           shape=18, size=3,show_guide = FALSE)
```

Comment: +1 for short, self-contained, reproducible example.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/15660829/1036500

Answer (score 104, accepted):

First, you can calculate the group means with `aggregate`:

```
means <- aggregate(weight ~  group, PlantGrowth, mean)
```

This dataset can be used with `geom_text`:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data=PlantGrowth, aes(x=group, y=weight, fill=group)) + geom_boxplot() +
  stat_summary(fun=mean, colour="darkred", geom="point", 
               shape=18, size=3, show.legend=FALSE) + 
  geom_text(data = means, aes(label = weight, y = weight + 0.08))
```

Here, `+ 0.08` is used to place the label above the point representing the mean.

[image]

---

An alternative version without `ggplot2`:

```
means <- aggregate(weight ~  group, PlantGrowth, mean)

boxplot(weight ~ group, PlantGrowth)
points(1:3, means$weight, col = "red")
text(1:3, means$weight + 0.08, labels = means$weight)
```

[image]

Comment: +1 - I had just worked this through and came to update my answer and BAM!. Well done.

Comment: How can you decrease the size of the text?

Comment: Also, how can you limit the number of decimals?

Comment: @MartinVelez For example, `geom_text(data = means, aes(label = round(weight, 1), y = weight + 0.08), size = 3)` creates smaller text with 1 decimal place.

Comment: @SvenHohenstein Thanks!  I am using `formatC(weight,2)`.

Comment: @SvenHohenstein is it possible to do this without ggplot?

Comment: @user4050 I added a section on how to create a similar plot without `ggplot2`. See the update.

Comment: @ Sven Hohenstein thank you, it was very helpful. I have one problem: when I used that line to show means of categories divided by gender the meanes were stacked in the same vertical axis, instead of being in the correspondent boxplot. How can correct that?

Comment: @mad This is hard to answer without knowing the `ggplot2` command.

Comment: @ Sven Hohenstein 
I'm sorry, below is the ggplot2 command: 

ggplot(ggchen[(4045*12+1):(4045*15),], aes(Rank, Eval, fill=Gen)) + geom_boxplot() + facet_grid(. ~ Question) + stat_summary(fun.y=mean, colour="darkred", geom="point", shape=18, size=3, show_guide=FALSE)

https://ibb.co/gOoZtv        <-- image

Comment: @mad Try to add the argument `position = position_dodge(width = 3/4)` to `stat_summary`.

Answer (score 38):

You can use the output value from `stat_summary()`

```
ggplot(data=PlantGrowth, aes(x=group, y=weight, fill=group)) 
+ geom_boxplot() 
+ stat_summary(fun.y=mean, colour="darkred", geom="point", hape=18, size=3,show_guide = FALSE)
+ stat_summary(fun.y=mean, colour="red", geom="text", show_guide = FALSE, 
               vjust=-0.7, aes( label=round(..y.., digits=1)))
```

Comment: I also want to add mean in the boxplots. So, I amended by box plot code by adding `stat_summary()` & `fill=x` but getting this error: `Error: Unknown parameters: hape In addition: Warning message:show_guide has been deprecated. Please use show.legend instead. ` What's wrong in your code?

Comment: I like this answer, because it doesn't make a new table or write a new function, but instead uses a built-in feature of `ggplot2` in the way `ggplot2` was designed, imho, namely `fun.y=mean, ... , geom="text"`. I just had to put the `+` signs at the ends of lines instead of the beginnings, so there is that issue, but that's an easy and obvious fix.

Answer (score 17):

You can also use a function within stat_summary to calculate the mean and the hjust argument to place the text, you need a additional function but no additional data frame:

```
fun_mean <- function(x){
  return(data.frame(y=mean(x),label=mean(x,na.rm=T)))}


ggplot(PlantGrowth,aes(x=group,y=weight)) +
geom_boxplot(aes(fill=group)) +
stat_summary(fun.y = mean, geom="point",colour="darkred", size=3) +
stat_summary(fun.data = fun_mean, geom="text", vjust=-0.7)
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

## The Magrittr way

I know there is an accepted answer already, but I wanted to show one cool way to do it in single command with the help of [magrittr](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/magrittr/vignettes/magrittr.html) package.

```
PlantGrowth %$% # open dataset and make colnames accessible with '$'
split(weight,group) %T>% # split by group and side-pipe it into boxplot
boxplot %>% # plot
lapply(mean) %>% # data from split can still be used thanks to side-pipe '%T>%'
unlist %T>% # convert to atomic and side-pipe it to points
points(pch=18)  %>% # add points for means to the boxplot
text(x=.+0.06,labels=.) # use the values to print text
```

This code will produce a boxplot with means printed as points and values:
[image: boxplot with means]

I split the command on multiple lines so I can comment on what each part does, but it can also be entered as a oneliner. You can learn more about this in my [gist](https://gist.github.com/janxkoci/7be5b31200c6d143f8700699fe6892b4).