# how to add text in my boxplot?

Tags: r

I have plotted box plot for my data using given command and trying to write text (p-value ) in it.

Using :

```
boxplot(data,ylab = prop_index[i])
text(1:2 - 0.4, data[,1]/2, paste("p-value=",p_val))
```

I applied "text" command but noting has appeared on image. Please tell me appropriate method to apply this command

[image: Box plots are given]

Comment: If you give a reproducible example one could possibly help you

Comment: Possibly the same http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28846348/add-number-of-observations-per-group-in-ggplot2-boxplot

Comment: @PierreLafortune, not a a duplicate--that one's `ggplot2`, this is base-plotting

Comment: @PierreLafortune please note: you are referring ggplot package

Answer (score 14):

```
x1 <- rnorm(500)
y1 <- sample(c("a", "b", "c"), 500, replace=T)
boxplot(x1 ~ y1)
text(x= 1, y= 3, labels= "some text")
text(x= 2, y= 3, labels= "more \n text")
text(x= 3, y= 3, labels= "red text", col= "red")
```

[image]

Comment: You can compress, the text additions into one line with `text(x= 1:3, y= 3, labels= c("some text","more \n text","red text"), col=c(NA,NA,"red"))`.

Comment: @eipi10 Good point / of course. I was just giving the example

Comment: How do you do this if only using a single x value (i.e., no actual x value is assigned in boxplot)? In other words, if using `boxplot(y)`