# Change stat_summary colours based on group and add text to the label in ggplot2 boxplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, label

Following this question: [Add number of observations per group in ggplot2 boxplot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28846348/add-number-of-observations-per-group-in-ggplot2-boxplot), how do I change the colours of stat_summary?

Below is the example code:

```
give.n <- function(x){
      return(c(y = median(x)*1.05, label = length(x))) 
    }    


p <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(factor(vs), mpg, colour = factor(am))) + 
      geom_boxplot() +
      stat_summary(fun.data = give.n, geom = "text", fun.y = median,
                   position = position_dodge(width = 0.75))
p
```

So when I do the below to change the colours, it doesn't work (it gives me only 1 combined number)

```
stat_summary(fun.data = give.n, geom = "text", fun.y = median,
                   position = position_dodge(width = 0.75), colour =   c("black", "red"))
```

And when I do the below to add the text "n=" it doesn't work either. (I try to add the "n=" in the function itself, by doing the below:

```
give.n <- function(x){
      return(c(y = median(x)*1.05, label = paste0("n=",length(x)))) 
    }
```

But I get the below error:

```
 Error: Discrete value supplied to continuous scale
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the colours, you want to add these using `scale_colour_manual`, so plot call looks like:

```
p <- 
    ggplot(mtcars, aes(factor(vs), mpg, colour = factor(am))) + 
    geom_boxplot() +
    stat_summary(fun.data = give.n, geom = "text", fun.y = median,
               position = position_dodge(width = 0.75)) +
    scale_colour_manual(values = c("black", "red"))
```

The answer to adding "n=" is a duplicate of this question: [Use stat_summary to annotate plot with number of observations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15720545/use-stat-summary-to-annotate-plot-with-number-of-observations).  You need to use `data.frame(...)` in your `give.n` function rather than `c(...)`:

```
give.n <- 
    function(x){
      return(data.frame(y = median(x)*1.05, label = paste0("n=",length(x)))) 
    }
```

EDIT:
Re comment on changing colours for stat_summary items only, this proved a bit tricky in that  I don't think you can have multiple `scale_colour_manual` layers.  However, in this case you can make use of the fill aesthetic for box plots and leave the colour aesthetic for your text geom.
To make it cleaner, I've taken the colour and fill aesthetics out of the `ggplot(...)` call and put these in each geom:

```
p <- 
    ggplot(mtcars, aes(factor(vs), mpg)) + 
    geom_boxplot(aes(fill = factor(am))) +
    stat_summary(aes(colour = factor(am)), fun.data = give.n, 
                 geom = "text", fun.y = median, position = position_dodge(width = 0.75)) +
    scale_colour_manual(values = c("black", "red"))
```

Then if you want to specify colours for the box plot fill you can use `scale_fill_manual(...)`

Comment: Thank you! somehow I overlooked the post you mentioned. This worked!  On a separate note, I wanted to change the colours of the stat_summary items ONLY, that is, I'd like to keep the colours of my boxplot as they are now, BUT have the number of observations be in black and red (for example). Your suggestion changed both. How do I ONLY change the stat_summary items? thanks!

Comment: @debbybeginner That one was a bit tricky but a solution is to use the fill aesthetic for the boxplot and leave the colour aesthetic for the stat_summary text geom.  Answer updated to reflect this.