# Grouped boxplot in R - where is my mistake?

Tags: r, ggplot2, boxplot

I tried using aes(x=..,y=..,fill=...) to plot a boxplot. Somehow it doesn't work. It is supposed to look something like this:

https://www.r-graph-gallery.com/265-grouped-boxplot-with-ggplot2.html (first picture)

but with added mean and standard deviation in red.

I have a dataframe which contains the number of a person `p` (asked in a survey), answers to two questions `q1` and `q2` (on a scale of 1 to 4) and a reference to which group `G` they belong. Could anyone help me find the error?

```
    library(mosaic) 
    library(effects) 
    library(openxlsx) 
    library(corrgram) 
    library(GGally) 
    library(vcd) 
    library(corrplot) 
    library(ggpubr)
    
    library(dplyr) 
    library(tidyr) 
    library(ggplot2) 
    
    
    
    l1 = c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,5,2,3,3,3,3,3,3,4,4,5,5,5,4,3,3,2,2,1,1,2,2,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,3,3,4,4,4,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,4,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,4,4,4,4,3,3,2,2,2,2)
    l2 = c("N/A","N/A","N/A","N/A","N/A","N/A","N/A","N/A","N/A","N/A",2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,2,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,2,2,2,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,4,4,4,4,4,3,3,3,3,2,2,2,1,1,1,1,1)
    l3 = c(1,2,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,1,2,1,2,2,2,2,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,1,1,1)
    
    df <- data.frame (p = c(1:20),
                      q1=l1[1:20],
                      q2=l2[1:20],
                      G=l3[1:20]
    )
    dfn<-df %>% replace_with_na_all(condition = ~.x == "N/A")
    dfn$q1<-as.numeric(dfn$q1)
    dfn$q2<-as.numeric(dfn$q2)
    dfn$G<-as.numeric(dfn$G)
                      
          
    
    #-----------------------------------------------------
    
    preparedataboxplot <- select(dfn,p,q1,q2,G) %>% gather(key='Question_num', value='Antwort', -c(p,G))
    preparedataboxplot <- preparedataboxplot %>% drop_na()
    preparedataboxplot$Antwort<-unlist(preparedataboxplot$Antwort)
    
preparedataboxplot$G[preparedataboxplot$G == 2] <- 'B'
preparedataboxplot$G[preparedataboxplot$G == 1] <- 'A'

    ggplot(preparedataboxplot,aes(x=factor(Question_num),y=Antwort,fill=G))+
      stat_boxplot()+
      geom_boxplot()+
stat_summary(fun=mean, geom="point", size=2,color="red")+
  stat_summary(
    fun.min = function(x) mean(x) - sd(x), 
    fun.max = function(x) mean(x) + sd(x))
```

Unforunately the mean and standard deviation in red does not separate for each question q1 but are displayed on top of each other between the boxplots for each group. How do I fix this?

[image]

Comment: You have to set position argument. Try with adding `position = position_dodge(.75)` to stat_summary.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28846348/add-number-of-observations-per-group-in-ggplot2-boxplot for a related issue with adding text labels.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the comments on my question from [stefan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12993861/stefan) I found a working solution:

```
ggplot(preparedataboxplot,aes(x=factor(Question_num),y=Antwort,fill=G))+
  stat_boxplot(geom='errorbar',width=0.8)+
  geom_boxplot(width=0.8)+
  stat_summary(position=position_dodge(.9),fun=mean, geom="point",size=2,color="red")+
  stat_summary(
    fun.min = function(x) mean(x) - sd(x), 
    fun.max = function(x) mean(x) + sd(x), 
    geom = "errorbar",
    color = "red",position=position_dodge(.9),
    width = .3
  )
```