# How to print mean, upper limit and lower limit and nrow of boxplot

Tags: r

My boxplot looks great, but I'd like to print on it how many samples make up each category as well as the upper and lower limit and mean

My boxplot is coded as follows:

```
boxplot(rainbow$CN~rainbow$IM,outline=FALSE,col=c("red","green","black"))
```

The dataframe this comes from is:

```
IM        CN
yes       3
no        12
yes       1
no        4
yes       9
```

Comment: Here is [ggplot solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15660829/how-to-add-a-number-of-observations-per-group-and-use-group-mean-in-ggplot2-boxp)

Comment: You could label it like this: `res <- boxplot(rainbow$CN~rainbow$IM); with(data.frame(x = 1:ncol(res$stats), y = as.vector(t(res$stats))), text(x, y, y))`.

Comment: Also just found out that boxplot2 will give the number of elements in each boxplot