# Add a number of observations per group AND SUBGROUP in ggplot2 boxplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, boxplot

This might seem like a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15660829/how-to-add-a-number-of-observations-per-group-and-use-group-mean-in-ggplot2-boxp/15661466#comment57381365_15661466), but in fact I want to expand the original question.

I want to annote the boxplot with the number of observations per group AND SUBGROUP in ggplot. Following the example or the original post, here is my minimal example:

```
require(ggplot2)

give.n <- function(x){
  return(c(y = median(x)*1.05, label = length(x))) 
  # experiment with the multiplier to find the perfect position
}

ggplot(mtcars, aes(factor(cyl), mpg, fill = factor(gear))) +
  geom_boxplot() +
  stat_summary(fun.data = give.n, geom = "text", fun.y = median)
```

My problem is that the number of samples all line up in the center of the group, rather than plotting on the appropriate boxplot (as the picture below shows):[image: Annotes are centering in the middle of the group rather than plotting on the appropriate boxplot]

Comment: If I understand you correctly, I think you need to facet_wrap.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

is it what you want?

```
require(ggplot2)

give.n <- function(x){
  return(c(y = median(x)*1.05, label = length(x))) 
  # experiment with the multiplier to find the perfect position
}

ggplot(mtcars, aes(factor(cyl), mpg, fill = factor(gear))) +
  geom_boxplot() +
  stat_summary(fun.data = give.n, geom = "text", fun.y = median, position=position_dodge(width=0.75))
```

[image]

Comment: exactly what I needed, thank you! Can I post a followup question? Please request deletion of this comment if this is bad practice. Otherwise: Using a factor to determin the position of the text in relation to the group median leads to unwanted behaviour if the values are far apart. Using a fixed value (e.g. median(x)+5) makes the function only usable for one range of values. Is there a way to determin the y value of the text within the stat_summary() command?

Comment: thanks for accepting the answer !to your comment, I am not sure, but I am personally more manual, but if you want to put label exactly where you want geom_text() is probably the best option

Comment: Alternative: instead of using a Multiple of the median per subgroup is there a way to access the median of the whole dataset and use a multiple of that value?

Comment: I think it's possible; take a look at this http://docs.ggplot2.org/dev/geom_boxplot.html and scroll down, you will see an example where you can draw a boxplot with your own computations

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone else is having trouble positioning the text at suitable locations, here is my modification to the answer from @MLavoie :

```
require(ggplot2)

give.n <- function(x){
  
  # Calculate the third quantile (q3) and the distance between the median and
  # q3:
  q3 <- quantile( x, probs = c(0.75), names = F )
  distance_between_median_and_q3 <- ( q3 - median(x))
  
  # If the distance between the median and 3rd quartile are large enough, place
  # text halfway between the median and 3rd quartile:
  if( distance_between_median_and_q3 > 0.8 ){
    return( c( 
      y = median(x) + (q3 - median(x))/2
      , label = length(x) )) 
  } else{
    # If the distance is too small, either:
    
    # 1) place text above upper whisker *as long as*  IQR = 0,
    if(IQR(x) > 0 ){
      upper_whisker <- max( x[ x < (q3 + 1.5 * IQR(x)) ])
      
      return( c( 
        y = upper_whisker * 1.03
        , label = length(x) )) 
    } else{
      # or 
      # 2) place text above median
      return( c( 
        y = median(x) * 1.03
        , label = length(x) )) 
    }
  }
}

ggplot(mtcars, aes(factor(cyl), mpg, fill = factor(gear))) +
  geom_boxplot() +
  stat_summary( fun.data = give.n
                , geom = "text"
                # , fun.y = median
                , position = position_dodge( width = 0.75 ) 
  )
```

Please note that you might have to experiment with some of the values or code in the `give.n` function to get it to work with your data. But as you can see, it is possible to make `give.n` quite flexible.

[image]