# How to add sample size used in plotting geom_jitter

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggpubr

I want to add how many samples were added to a graph, next to my stat_cor (ggpubr) text.

I'm using the following code to generate the graph:

```
dataset = mtcars

 ggplot(dataset,  aes(dataset$wt, dataset$disp)) +
 geom_jitter()  +
 geom_smooth(level=0.95, method = "loess") +
 stat_cor(method="spearman") + 
 theme_classic()
```

But, if I want to plot multiple graphs in one figure, which uses a real data set where different variables have different missing values, it would be nice to have my sample size used to plot the geom_jitter.

Comment: As an aside: [don't use `$` in `aes()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32543753/8583393); use `ggplot(mtcars,  aes(wt, disp))`

Comment: As I understand, this issue has been solved (https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/pull/2694)

Comment: Using `$ in aes()` is still bad practice... there's no advantage to doing it`$`. It doesn't break facets anymore, but still may have other unintended consequences (in the past it's certainly caused issues when using binning functions as well, e.g., `stat_bin_2d`)

Comment: I found out that using $ in aes is sometimes needed when you have special characters in you colname, although I'm not experienced enough with R to give a description as to why this happens (I never tried to find why, just found a workaround). I agree that I should be aware of doing this, thanks for point out.

Comment: If you're using special characters in your column names you need backticks, but you shouldn't need `$`.

Answer (score 4):

It's a little hacky (and limited in its options), but you can use the `label.sep` argument to insert the sample  size between the correlation coefficient and the p-value (note that somewhat older version of `ggpubr` have a bug with `label.sep`... if this doesn't work for you, try updating your package)

```
ggplot(mtcars,  aes(wt, disp)) +
  geom_jitter()  +
  geom_smooth(level = 0.95, method = "loess") +
  stat_cor(method = "spearman", label.sep = sprintf(", n = %s, ", nrow(mtcars))) +
  theme_classic()
```

[image]

If your concern is missing values, you might need to use a different function than `nrow`, but I'll leave that to you. This also will not work with facets (you'll get the same number in each facet).

For a fully flexible solution, I think you could use a `geom_text`, or maybe a `stat_summary` with `geom = "text"` would be possible?

[Or go hardcore like this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42822273/adding-sample-size-to-a-box-plot-at-the-min-or-max-of-the-facet-in-ggplot), if nothing else works

Just for completeness on missing values:

```
ggplot(mtcars,  aes(wt, disp)) +
geom_jitter()  +
geom_smooth(level = 0.95, method = "loess") +
stat_cor(method = "spearman", label.sep = 
  sprintf(", n = %s, ", 
    sum(complete.cases(mtcars[c("wt","disp")]))
  )) +
theme_classic()
```

To plot the value of N on complete cases of wt and disp as the example shows

Comment: I added some code to assess N on multiple complete.cases on any collumns