# Print total number for each groups with ggboxplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggpubr

Is there anyway to print total number (eg. n = xxx, either on x-axis  or inside the boxplot) for each group when using ggboxplot?

Comment: Why use *ggpubr*, try using *ggplot2* geom_boxplot, see example here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15660829/how-to-add-a-number-of-observations-per-group-and-use-group-mean-in-ggplot2-boxp

Comment: @zx8754 doesn't answer the question. There are numerous why one might want to use a secondary level library for convenience.

Comment: @posdef It is just a comment with a link (not an answer), which helps put together related posts. In case others wish to use ggplot solution instead of ggpubr.

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out by myself, should use:

```
ggboxplot( ) + scale_x_discrete(labels = c())
```

Comment: If this has worked, consider accepting as an answer.