# Automatic n plotting with ggplot and stat_summary

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

This is a question related to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15720545/use-stat-summary-to-annotate-plot-with-number-of-observations/15720769#15720769). I'm dealing with a boxplot of two groups and used the function n_fun proposed in that question with a small modification (I used y=10 to locate the "n = " because I find it disturbing above the median).

Here's the function:

```
n_fun <- function(x){
  return(data.frame(y = 10, label = paste0("n = ",length(x))))
} 

ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=factor(cyl), mpg, fill=factor(am))) +  
geom_boxplot() + stat_summary(fun.data = n_fun, geom = "text")
```

The thing is that the function recognizes that there are two different "n = " to be plotted but they get plotted together on a single `'y'`. I've tried to enter a vector on the y position of the `n_fun` and it is accepted. However, I get two overplotted "n= ". I'm looking for something like "position = dodge" for the `stat_summary` or another way to tell the `ggplot` that it must plot those texts in the same way that it plot's the dodged boxplots.

Comment: `stat_summary(fun.data = n_fun, geom = "text", position = position_dodge(.9))`?

Comment: @lukeA Great! that should be an answer. It also might help to explain why position = dodge does not work but position= position_dodge() does the job

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, as the help `?position_dodge` states: Dodging things with different widths can be tricky. You may need to explicitly specify the width for dodging. In your case:

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=factor(cyl), mpg, fill=factor(am))) +  
  stat_summary(fun.data = n_fun, geom = "text", 
               position = position_dodge(.9))
```