# ggplot 2, boxplot add mean with legend

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to add for my ggplot boxplot a mean with a legend, but I don't know how.

The follwing R script is include in a function for a single variable:

```
p2 <- ggplot(df, aes("",!!sym(x))) +
    geom_boxplot() +
    stat_summary(fun=mean, geom="crossbar", color="steelblue2")
```

Thanks.

Comment: Try `stat_summary(fun = mean, geom = "crossbar", mapping = aes(colour = "mean"))`.

Answer (score 0):

adapted from this solution [Use stat_summary to annotate plot with number of observations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15720545/use-stat-summary-to-annotate-plot-with-number-of-observations) you could try something like this:

```
fun_mean <- function(x) {return(data.frame(y = mean(x), 
                                           label = paste0("mean = ", round(mean(x), 2))))}
ggplot(mtcars, aes(factor(cyl), mpg, label = rownames(mtcars))) +
geom_boxplot(fill = "grey80", colour = "#3366FF") + 
stat_summary(fun.data = fun_mean, geom = "text")
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Actually, i want to add a legend with crossbar to specify mean.