# Vertical position of stat_summary() in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, boxplot

I am trying to do something like the first solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3483203/create-a-boxplot-in-r-that-labels-a-box-with-the-sample-size-n):

```
give.n <- function(x){
   return(c(y = mean(x), label = length(x)))
}
ggplot(diamonds, aes(cut, price)) + 
   geom_boxplot() + 
   stat_summary(fun.data = give.n, geom = "text")
```

But I want those sample sizes to be displayed at position y = 0, not in the boxes of the boxplots. How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function `give.n()` returns both, the y-coordinate at which to display the number and the number to be displayed (i.e., the label). You simply need to change the y-coordinate returned by `give.n()`:

```
give.n <- function(x){
   return(c(y = 0, label = length(x)))
}
```